# How to customize related_name argument in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I have an abstract model and two child models such as:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", related_name='%(class)s')

    class Meta:
        abstract=True

class SaleInvoice(Invoice):
    field_sale = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class PurchaseInvoice(Invoice):
    field_purchase = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Now the reverse name for the child models would be `saleinvoices` and `purchaseinvoices`. But what I need is `sale_invoices` and `purchase_invoices`. How to achieve this? An underscore in between CamelCase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. override the **`contribute_to_class()`** of **`ForeignKey`** to set the ***related_name***.

```
class CustomFk(models.ForeignKey):
    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name, private_only=False, **kwargs):
        super().contribute_to_class(cls, name, private_only=False, **kwargs)
        self.remote_field.related_name = "_".join(re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', cls.__name__))
```

2. Use this ***custom FK field*** in abstract model.

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    user = CustomFk(User, related_name='%(class)s')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

```
# migrations file
operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='PurchaseInvoice',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('field_purchase', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
            ('user', sample.models.CustomFk(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE,
                                            related_name='Purchase_Invoice', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
        ],
        options={
            'abstract': False,
        },
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='SaleInvoice',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('field_sale', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
            ('user', sample.models.CustomFk(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE,
                                            related_name='Sale_Invoice', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
        ],
        options={
            'abstract': False,
        },
    ),
]
```

**Reference**
*. [**`contribute_to_class()`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219277/django-get-a-fields-name-from-within-its-init-function) 
*. [Split string with uppercase letters- Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277352/split-a-string-at-uppercase-letters)